# What are alternatives for "may" in past sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

Sometimes I make sentences like these:

> - I may couldn't convey my meaning.
> - You may didn't consider the point.
> - you may misunderstood my point.

I think after "may" I must use the bare infinitive form of a verb, so the above sentences are not grammatical. So, what are the alternatives for such sentences so that I can add probability or uncertainty to an event in the past?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say in these sentences. All of them would be grammatical if you simply removed the "may".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just want to add probability to them... For example `I couldn't prbably convey my meaning` However, it's an alternative I know. I asked from such alternatives....

Comment: @Ahmad It isn't true that after "may" you use the present form of the verb.  After "may", you use the bare infinitive (which doesn't add "s" in the third person singular).  E.g. we say "she goes" (present tense)  but "she may go" (not "goes").  And "she is" (present) but "she may be" ("be" is the bare infinitive).  Anyway, modal verbs (like "may", "could") lack infinitives - it follows that *"I may could" is ungrammatical in standard English (because "could" isn't an infinitive).

Comment: @rjpond thank you, I modified my question

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "may" with words like "couldn't". You need to rephrase:

> I may not have been able to convey my meaning.
> You may not have considered the point.
> You may have misunderstood my point.